# Which option is correct here? has come/came

Tags: grammar, tenses

I don't know which of these sentences is correct:

- The holy ghost has come upon me
- The holy ghost came upon me

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context. "The Holy Ghost has come upon me" implies that the experience is continuing up to the present moment. This could be spoken immediately after the beginning of the experience, for instance in a prayer meeting, or years after the experience started expressing a permanent change in one's perception of the world.

"The Holy Ghost came upon me" expresses an experience which has passed (although it could have resulted in a profound change in one's life). The context could be talking about the prayer meeting referred to above, being inspired to preach, being inspired to train for the ministry or any number of other things.

Comment: Could you write a sentence that exemplifies the second usage (*years after the experience...*) of the present perfect you mention?

Comment: @AlanCarmack The sort of thing that people say is: _"I was a compulsive gambler and I prayed for deliverance, **The Holy Spirit came upon me** and I was given the strength to resist. I joined Gamblers Anonymous and have not placed a bet or used a gaming machine for ten years."_ This is not my experience or a direct quote but is similar to stories that I have read or heard in the past.